# How to use Autocomplete for google places in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, autocomplete

Can anyone help me to how to use Autocomplete for google places for android. Any link or Examples would be helpful.

Comment: so you dont know how to request any web service from your ACTV or you know how to do it but dont know how to use google places api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example :

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
            String check = textView.getText().toString();
            if (check.trim().isEmpty()) {
                // do something here
                }
            } else {
                // now pass the argument in the textview to the task
                task.execute(check);
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        // get the list of predictions in an asynctask
        class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

            @Override
            // three dots is java for an array of strings
            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args) {
                ArrayList<String> predictionsArr = new ArrayList<String>();

                try {
                    URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                            // URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
                            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="
                                    + URLEncoder.encode(args[0].toString(),
                                            "UTF-8")
                                    + "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=import-hash-key-here");

                    URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

                    String line;
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    // take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big
                    // string.
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    // turn that string into a JSON object
                    JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                    // now get the JSON array that's inside that object
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions
                            .getString("predictions"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                        // add each entry to our array
                        predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
                // return all the predictions based on the typing the in the
                // search
                return predictionsArr;

            }

            // then our post

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
                // put all the information in the list view to display
                Log.d("YourApp", "onPostExecute : " + result.size());
                // update the adapter
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                        R.layout.list_item);// show the list view as texts
                // attach the adapter to listView
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                for (String string : result) {
                    adapter.add(string);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                next.setClickable(true);
            }

        }

    });
```

**You generate the key from google developer console**

I am ready to assist you further

Comment: Here is a good place to get started : https://developers.google.com/places/android/?hl=en